# how to create decimal field in access database?

Tags: python, python-2.7, ms-access, ms-access-2010, win32com

I have used bellow code to create decimal column in accessdb, But when I execute the code it returns `field definition error`

```
dbname = r'C:/Users/Dhana/Documents/NewDB.accdb'
accApp = Dispatch("Access.Application")
dbEngine = accApp.DBEngine
workspace = dbEngine.Workspaces(0)

dbLangGeneral = ';LANGID=0x0409;CP=1252;COUNTRY=0'
newdb = workspace.CreateDatabase(dbname, dbLangGeneral, 64)

newdb.Execute("""CREATE TABLE AAA (ID COUNTER, Field1 DECIMAL(10,3));""")
```

But I am able create the decimal field through access database interface(GUI). Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: A hint from http://allenbrowne.com/ser-49.html : [DECIMAL] *Not available in the Access query interface or DAO. Use ADO to Execute the DDL query statement.* (not 100% sure this is the issue)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andre is right, the issue is that you can't use the `DECIMAL` data type in DAO, you need ADO.

You can use the following:

```
dbname = r'C:/Users/Dhana/Documents/NewDB.accdb'
accApp = Dispatch("Access.Application")
dbEngine = accApp.DBEngine
workspace = dbEngine.Workspaces(0)

dbLangGeneral = ';LANGID=0x0409;CP=1252;COUNTRY=0'
newdb = workspace.CreateDatabase(dbname, dbLangGeneral, 64)
conn = accApp.CurrentProject.Connection
conn.Execute("CREATE TABLE AAA (ID COUNTER, Field1 DECIMAL(10,3));")
```